# How to check if the mysqli_object has been freed?

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to check if the [mysqli_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) has been freed.

With the [Ext/Mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) functions you could do it with the function [is_resource](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-resource.php)

I tried checking if $result is an istance of mysqli_result, but **after been freed $result is still a mysqli_result object**

```
$db = mysqli_connect("myhost", "myuser", "mypass", "mydb");
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$result->free();
var_dump(is_a($result, "mysqli_result")); // => true, it is even if freed
```

Answer (score 1):

After you freed the mysqli_result, its `num_rows` property ist set to NULL.

If you check it, php will throw a warning

> PHP Warning: Couldn't fetch mysqli_result

Since you know that this wouldn´t be an error, you can ignore it with `@`.

```
function isFreed(mysqli_result $result) {
    return @($result->num_rows === NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you wrap it in some function or method?

```
Class Result
{
    private $result;

    public function __construct(mysqli_result $result) {
        $this->result = $result;
    }

    public function getResult() {
        return $this->result;
    }

    public function free() {
        $this->result->free();
        $this->result = null;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->free();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could instead check, if the result of

```
$result->free()
```

returns true, because if it would return false, it failed.

Would that be enough for checking?

Comment: mysqli_free_result returns no value, and each subsequent call will throw a warning.

Comment: Hmm, ok... my bad. May have skipped, that we are using mysqli_free_result instead of mysql_free_result